# Amsbook class + two tables of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, amsbook, etoc, shorttoc

I would like to show two tables of contents with the amsbook class: Consider the following MWE,

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\shorttoc{Contents}{1}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Some subsubsection text

\end{document}
```

This doesn't compile, but funnily only after compiling twice: If I compile without the `\shorttoc` command I generate the table of contents as usual; then I uncomment `\shorttoc` and it still compiles, now *correctly* generating two tables of contents; then I compile again and get the following error.

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.1 ...tents}}}\xdef {}{}{}\mark {}\endgroup }}{3}
%
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
) [3
] [4
]
Contents (detailed)
(./MWE.toc
```

Is this an incompatibility of shorttoc and amsbook? Any workarounds to have two tables of contents? I'm not set on using `shorttoc` either. But `etoc`, `tocloft` etc. seem to generate other problems with AMS classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I define `\firstToC` to print the first Table of Contents and `\secondToC` to print the second one. The first one turns off overwriting of the `.toc` (setting `\@fileswfalse`, locally). The second removes the printing of the ToC within the ToC (again, locally).

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstToC}{{%
  \@fileswfalse% Don't overwrite the current ToC
  \@starttoc{toc}\contentsname
}}
\newcommand{\secondToC}{{%
  \renewcommand{\@tocwrite}[2]{}% Don't write ToC to ToC
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents (detailed)}%
  \@starttoc{toc}{\contentsname}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}%
\firstToC

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}%
\secondToC

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Lorem ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to change in `\starttoc` to make it compatible with `amsbook`:

1. we want to avoid that it writes an entry in the table of contents, which `\chapter*` normally does in `amsbook`;
2. we don't want that it takes the initiative to set the headers, because `amsbook` takes care of the business anyway.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\shorttoc[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \c@tocdepth=#2\relax
  \@restonecolfalse
  \if@tightshtoc
    \parsep\z@
  \fi
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
  \renewcommand\@tocwriteb[3]{}%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \@startshorttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\shorttoc{Contents}{1}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents (detailed)}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Some subsubsection text

\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\shorttoc` is essentially the same as in the package, but

1. `\@tocwriteb` is (locally) disabled in order not to produce a TOC entry
2. `\chapter*{#1}` does not issue `\@mkboth`.

#### Short contents

[image]

#### Detailed contents

[image]

Comment: This is a very instructive answer, as it tells me what to modify in shorttoc exactly to make things work. I would have accepted both answers if I could, but accepted @Werner's answer as I believe it was posted first.